# Remote debugger doesn't work after format - Visual Studio 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, remote-debugging

I need a tip to configure again my debugger on my local machine, after a format.

I have a Win2003Server with Remote Debugger in execution as service, and, until yesterday, everything works fine.
I formatted my client machine and re-installed all my software, including Visual Studio 2005 with SP1. I connected to local domain with the same previous user.

Now when I try to connect to Remote Debugger I've got this error message:

> Error: Remote Debugger Service is
>   Unable to Connect to This Computer

I've seen many articles on the net, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164725%28VS.80%29.aspx), but I can't be able to restore the previous settings. In another PC of my colleague, I've been able to see that all my settings are the same of him, except for presence of the "**BUILTIN**" group in "**Log on as a service**" in the "**Local Security Settings \ Local Security Settings \User Rights Assignment**".

I think I have to add the same in my PC.
Am I right?
How can I do this?

Comment: Please, any help appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link you point to indicates that you need to run msvsmon from an account with "Logon as a service" enabled.  A little searching around here points toward this blog post outlining some more potential requirements, like administrator privileges, permissions, 'back-authenticating' from the remote application machine to the local Visual Studio machine, etc.  Judging by the error, the remote debugging service is probably unable to connect back to the Visual Studio PC.

http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2008/05/15/visual-studio-remote-debugger-service-user-account-requirements.aspx

Note that there's a nested blog post in there that explains how to run the remote debug monitor from a local (interactive) account, instead of the remote debugging service.  If you still can't get the service to work, you could try creating identical accounts on both machines (preferably administrator) to help with back-authenticating.

Make sure you run everything as administrator, check firewall settings, not sure what else it could be.